# How can I access textview of other items when I click on another item in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a hidden textView in listView item layout and when the item is clicked, I am displaying that hidden textView. However, when I click another item, I want the other visible textview in item to be hidden again. So how can I access the textView of this other item?

```
theListView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                        TextView itemView2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                        itemView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        itemView2.setBackgroundColor(color.white);

                        Double lat = Double.parseDouble(((KioskInfo)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getLat());
                        Double lng = Double.parseDouble(((KioskInfo)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getLng());
                        LatLng itemLocation = new LatLng(lat,lng);

                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(itemLocation, 18 ));

                    }
                        });
```

item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/loginblue"></TextView>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/loginblue"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you use a Custom Adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember the index/position of the selected item in your ListView. Then, if another item is selected, you test if there already is another selected item. If so you can get that item's view like so:

```
// Hide previously selected text view
if (selectedIndex > -1) {
    int viewIndex = selectedIndex - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    // if previously selected list item is still visible, hide its text view
    if (viewIndex > -1 && viewIndex < listView.getChildCount()) {
        View itemView = listView.getChildAt(viewIndex);
        TextView textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

// Now you make the newly selected text view visible and remember the selected item
selectedIndex = position;
```

`selectedIndex` is an instance variable of either your click listener or any other surrounding class. Initialize it with `-1` as no item is selected in the beginning.

Obviously you can optimize the code. It just to clarify to basic steps to accomplish your task.

Comment: Thank you, Lars. After changing listView with parent parameter, it worked. However, I am updating my accepted answer with Techfist. Because, it worked with less code. getFirstVisiblePosition was unnecessary and confused me a little bit and also the check in if for being small than the getChildCount.

Comment: @FigenGüngör I commented on Techfirst's solution as the `getFirstVisiblePosition` operation can become necessary

Comment: Sorry, Lars. I guess I haven't tested it properly. Thank you for the explanation, too.

Comment: Hi, Lars. I am having a  problem when my listview has many items and when I chose the first item, 7th and 14th items are also looks like clicked. What might be the reason?

Comment: What code do you use to mark items as selected? I think it's best to start a very new question on SO.

Comment: I added a selected boolean to my model and solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

define this as member variable in your activity,

```
int clickedPosition = -1;
```

then use this code,

```
            heListView.setOnItemClickListener(
                    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

                            if(clickedPosition!= position && clickedPosition != -1){
                                clickedPosition = position;
                                View previousView = heListView.getChildAt(clickedPosition);
                                TextView itemView2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                                itemView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                            TextView itemView2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                            itemView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            itemView2.setBackgroundColor(color.white);

                            Double lat = Double.parseDouble(((KioskInfo)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getLat());
                            Double lng = Double.parseDouble(((KioskInfo)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getLng());
                            LatLng itemLocation = new LatLng(lat,lng);

                            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(itemLocation, 18 ));

                        }
                            });
```

Comment: At the moment that your list view contains more items than the amount of visible items, it's necessary to subtract `getFirstVisiblePosition()` from the selection position. Your list view might show only 3 items whilst it contains an overall amount of 10 items, thus being 7 items not visible. If you then start to scroll down you'll then find an exception when calling `theListView.getChildAt(3).` as it only knows sub views from index 0 to 2, regardless of the scrolling position.